# How to use DataGridView's writing to unique datatables to write a singular XML File

Tags: vb.net

First post here.

I am currently responsible for creating a program which writes xml files.

Here is the deal. I have multiple datatables within a dataset that I am using. I need to generate ONE single xml file populated from these tables. I am populating the tables using a datagridview. I have three datagrids on my form, each linked to a different datatable. I need to allow the user to populate these grids and then generate a single xml file.

Currently I have had success using one datagrid to generate an xml file. However, the project requires multiple datatables be used in the xml file.

Thank you!

Comment: Loop through the DataTables, with an inner loop on the tables's rows, then one more inner loop on the fields, all while outputting to an `XmlWriter`.

Comment: `First post here.` Which means you should have read [ask] and taken the [tour].  The rest depends on how you are really generating the XML.  DataGridView doesnt have that capability as far as I know, the datasource does though

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've tried my best to research the XmlWriter but I am a bit confused. The idea is i go line by line and write each line to the xml file?

Comment: I made a quick example for you.  You should take a few minutes and try to improve your question though. a good start would be to show a small example of the output XML that you want to see, and any code you have already tried, or are confused by.  You said you have a working example for one table, that code would be great to add to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just issue a WriteXML on your dataset. Like

```
ds.WriteXML("<filename including path where you want to store the xml file>")
```

Comment: Insanely simple but exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of walking through a `DataSet` with multiple `DataTables` and writing the data to XML as it goes.  There are many different schemas this could take, so you will most likely have to modify this code slightly to make the output look like you want.

```
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dataset As New DataSet
        dataset.Tables.Add(CreateDataTable("Table1", 5))
        dataset.Tables.Add(CreateDataTable("Table2", 8))

        Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml",
                                                     New XmlWriterSettings() With {.Indent = True})
            writer.WriteStartDocument()
            writer.WriteStartElement("Dataset")
            For Each table As DataTable In dataset.Tables
                writer.WriteStartElement("Table")
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", table.TableName)
                For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Row")
                    For Each column As DataColumn In table.Columns
                        writer.WriteStartElement(column.ColumnName)
                        writer.WriteValue(row(column))
                        writer.WriteEndElement()
                    Next
                    writer.WriteEndElement()
                Next
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            Next
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndDocument()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function CreateDataTable(name As String, rows As Integer) As DataTable
        Dim table As New DataTable(name)
        table.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Col3", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Col4", GetType(String))

        For r As Integer = 1 To rows
            Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
            table.Rows.Add(row)
            For i As Integer = 1 To table.Columns.Count
                row(i - 1) = $"Row {r}, column {i}"
            Next
        Next
        Return table
    End Function
End Module
```

The `XmlWriter` works internally as a state-machine, you write elements, attributes, and values as you go, then call a generic `WriteCloseElement` that finishes the element in progress.

This just creates the document element, and a root element named "Dataset".  Then it loops through each `DataTable`, writing the a "Table" element for each one with the table's "Name" attribute.  Then it loops through each `DataRow` in the `DataTable`, writing a "Row" element.  Within each "row" element, it loops through all the `DataColumn`s in the `DataTable` and writes a new Element with the same name as the `DataColumn`.  Then it writes the value of that `DataColumn` on that `DataRow`.  It closes each element as it exits the loop.

It produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Dataset>
  <Table Name="Table1">
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 1, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 1, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 1, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 1, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 2, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 2, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 2, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 2, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 3, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 3, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 3, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 3, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 4, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 4, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 4, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 4, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 5, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 5, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 5, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 5, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="Table2">
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 1, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 1, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 1, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 1, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 2, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 2, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 2, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 2, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 3, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 3, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 3, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 3, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 4, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 4, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 4, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 4, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 5, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 5, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 5, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 5, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 6, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 6, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 6, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 6, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 7, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 7, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 7, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 7, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col1>Row 8, column 1</Col1>
      <Col2>Row 8, column 2</Col2>
      <Col3>Row 8, column 3</Col3>
      <Col4>Row 8, column 4</Col4>
    </Row>
  </Table>
</Dataset>
```